# Get File Data To the Text Box in HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have to get data  from the file to my text box. I have tried a lot in `Java Script` but no solution can some one help me out. I get output as `[object HTMLInputElement]` always when i try to get data from the file.

If i give `fileinput.value` then it shows File Name. If i add `fileinput` it shows `[object HTMLInputElement]`

```
<html>
<body> 
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

function BrowseButtonAction()
{
    var fileinput = document.getElementById('browse');
    fileinput.click();
}
function ChangeBrowseButton()
{
var fileinput = document.getElementById('browse');
var textinput = document.getElementById('filename');
textinput.value = fileinput.value;
}
</script>

<input type='text' id='filename' name='filename'/>
<input type='File' id='browse' name='fileupload' style='display: none' onChange='ChangeBrowseButton();'/>
<input type='button' value='File You need' id='fakeBrowse' onclick='BrowseButtonAction();'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `If i add fileinput it shows [object HTMLInputElement]` is a correct behaviour of javascript - what do you expect ?

Comment: I need the data from the file not the file name or [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: what kind of file is it?

Comment: You need to read code for reading file, fileinput.value wont give you file data.

Comment: fileinput.value does not give me any file data See this http://jsfiddle.net/PKVq5/1/

Comment: @Rachel Gallen I need it in JS not in Java read my requirement correctly

Comment: @ashokramcse why the java tag then?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Most of the Java Users will be knowing JS So only

Comment: @Rachel Gallen I have already tried http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ no use. See this http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ae3VH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fA2y/1/) might help you.

```
 fileinput.value isn't the correct way.Use HTML5 FileReader API.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you...It can show .txt file content

```
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" />

<script type="text/javascript">

  function readFile(evt) 
  {
    //Retrieve the file 
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if(f) 
    {
      var r = new FileReader();

      r.onload = function(e) 
      { 
          var contents = e.target.result;
          document.write(contents);
          // Set to the whatever textbox value
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    }
    else 
    { 
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
</script>
```

Comment: select any .txt file, content will be printed on the browser

Comment: This might not work in IE, try in Chrome or Mozilla.